# how to install ZED camera in ubuntu 14.04 CUDA 9 and ubuntu 14.04 CPU

Tags: ros, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

system:

```
nvidia-msi
nvidia-msi: command not found
redhwan@red:~$ nvidia-smi
Fri Jan 18 15:46:07 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 30%   31C    P0   ERR! /  75W |    766MiB /  4038MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1232      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           311MiB |
|    0      2280      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         204MiB |
|    0      5852      G   ...uest-channel-token=13684549950990594447   247MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+


redhwan@red:~$ nvcc --version

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver

Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation

Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017

Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176



redhwan@red:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Release:    14.04

Codename:   trusty
```

I followed from this link [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/zed-ros-wrapper)

the output:

```
CMake Error at zed-ros-wrapper/zed_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:17 (message):

   ZED SDK not found, install it from:
   https://www.stereolabs.com/developers/ 

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  zed-ros-wrapper/zed_wrapper/CMakeLists.txt:23 (checkPackage)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/redhwan/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/redhwan/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Invoking "cmake" failed
```

please help me

thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313086/how-to-install-zed--camera-in-ubuntu-14.04-cuda-9-and-ubuntu-14.04-cpu/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HankYuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37725/hankyuan/) on 2019-02-13**:
You can find the SDK in Stereolabs website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps not what you want(ed) to hear, but have you asked Stereolabs?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1